# select query for CLOB xml

Tags: xml, oracle, select, clob

I want to extract xml data stored in XMLDATA column
my table FINAL_XML has following columns

```
IDENTIFIERTYPE | IDENTIFIER | DATE      | XMLDATA
-------------- | ---------- | --------- | -------
CONTACT        | 1          |0216-08-04 | CLOB, 4500 Bytes
```

Is there a way to write a select statement which would return actual xml tree?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "actual xml tree"? Do you need a XMLTYPE result?

Comment: yes. if i select XMLDATA from FINAL_XML, it will return CLOB, 4500 Bytes and i would like to see what is inside

Comment: Maybe you simply need `select xmltype(XMLDATA) from FINAL_XML`

Comment: yes! please add is as answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your `CLOB` to the `XMLTYPE` type:

```
select xmltype(XMLDATA) from FINAL_XML
```

This will give you an error if your `CLOB` field is not a valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below how to read xml data from a column of xmltype:

```
SELECT x.xml_data.getClobVal()
FROM   xml_tab x;
```

If your XMLDATA column is of xmltype datatype then you query goes like:

```
SELECT  xmldata.getClobVal()
    FROM  FINAL_XML;
```